# Calling an assignment operator for one of bases with vtables of multiple-inherited derived class in C++

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

Ok, it's going to a bit a bit tricky. Here is a (simplified) code:

```
class A
{
    virtual ~A();
    // fields, none of which has an assignment operator or copy constructor
};

class B
{
    virtual ~B();
    // same as A
};

class Derived : public A, public B
{
    Derived();
    Derived(const B& b);
    // no fields
};
```

With `Derived::Derived(const B& b)` (i.e. accepting one of it's bases) as follows

```
Derived::Derived(const B& b)
{
    *static_cast<B*>(this) = b;
    // Do other stuff with protected fields declared in B
}
```

For me it's something in line of "just avoid doing this way", but that's an existing code and we are experiencing a subtle memory corruption suspiciously near this code. So, I'm curious if that's ok.

The curious part here is that both base classes have vtables and none of them has any explicit copy/assignment constructors/operators.

From my understanding, memory layout for a `Derived` class is as follows

```
 `Derived`
 ---------
 A-vtable
 A-fields
 B-vtable
 B-fields
```

And when I'm calling a virtual function, declared in "B" I'm using `B-vtable` and when I'm calling a virtual function, declared in "A" I'm using `A-vtable`, i.e. vtables are not merged together.

And from my understanding implicit copy/assignment constructor/operator for B should only affect `B-fields`, when it's called as `*static_cast<B*>(this) = b;` (`static_cast` should give a pointer to start of `B-fields`, with `B-vtable` residing at a negative offset from it, AFAIK).

So, from my understanding, this code is perfectly safe and correct, though unclear and hacky, but safe. Am I correct? Are there any compiler-specific quirks I should be aware of (we are talking about MSVC 2012 here)?

**Edit:** Guys, I know about copy constructor/assignment operator difference, thank you very much. It was one of 3 occurrences that was talking about just copy constructor, because I've oversaw it, and now every answer spends half of the text to tell the completely unrelevant to the question difference.

Comment: "experiencing a subtle memory corruption suspiciously near this code" - go and extract a minimal example then!

Comment: Pointers like `this` typically point to the hidden field where the vtable pointer is stored (i.e. to the very beginning of the object, not to an offset to it), because it is used pretty often. Whether the pointer came from a static cast or not is irrelevant. I think it could also be at a negative offset, that is probably an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct. There is this peculiar behavior of casting a derived class to one of its parents. When multiple inheritance occurs, like in your case, the actual address of the pointer can change. To use your exampe:

```
this                     ->   | A-vtable |
                              | A-fields |
static_cast<B*>(this)    ->   | B-vtable |
                              | B-fields |
```

The same change of pointer in this happens when you call a function derived from `B` on a `Derived` object.

---

However, be aware that copy constructor is *not* what you invoke in the line:

```
*static_cast<B*>(this) = b;
```

Instead, you are invoking an assignment operator of `B`, i.e. `B::operator=(const B& other)`. If you didn't define one, the default assignment operator is used. The equal sign is treated as a copy constructor only in the context of variable declaration:

```
B newObj = b;
```

If you want to implement your own copy constructor for the `Derived` and then explicitly invoke the parent copy constructor of `B`, try this instead:

```
Derived::Derived(const B& b) : B(b)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just call constructor of base class?

```
Derived::Derived(const B& b)
: B(b)
{
}
```

Similar thing can be done for assignment operators:

```
Deriver& Derived::operator=(const Derived& rhs)
{
    A::operator=(rhs); //Assign A's part
    B::operator=(rhs); //Assign B's part
    //Derived-specific assignments

    return *this;
}
```

This the preferred, safe and totally valid way to initialize objects of classes, that inherit from something.

Also, in this line:

```
*static_cast<B*>(this) = b;
```

you call assignment operator, not copy constructor. Since you wrote, that neither of base types has them defined, default (generated by the compiler) is used.

I don't understand why are you even thinking about vtables. This is simple inheritance from classes with compiler-generated copy constructors and assignment operators. Everything is simple and can be done without any hacks :)

Comment: This is not my code, I'm usually avoiding inheritance at all, left aside multiple inheritance. I understand that there are other ways to do this without hacks, but question isn't about that. Question is about - is THAT way is safe or not. But thanks anyway, I was wondering if calling a fully qualified operator will do the same.