# IDA pro - what does the invert sign mean in -> mov eax, [ecx-14h]?

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida

This is my first question on StackOverflow, and I hope I find an answer. I'm a newbie in reverse-engineering, I still have a lot to learn.

I started to reverse-engineer a C++ DirectX game a couple of years ago. Everything was pretty much good, until I hit this case.

I'm trying to reverse-engineer a class that inherits from 2 abstract classes,
eg `CClass : IClass, IBaseClass`. Apparently, the 2 classes are abstract classes, specially `IBaseClass`, and in the virtual functions that belong to `IBaseClass`, the offsets of members are weird for me.

Let me pick an example of a getter function from `IBaseClass`:

[image: disasm]

This function returns `(this - 0x8)`:

[image: pseudo code]

What does it mean, and how could it be possibly handled while creating the structure, assuming that class members are only accessible by, for eg, `return (this + 0x8)`, `+` not `-`, or so I thought.

I assumed the class is like this:

```cpp
struct CClass {
    CClass::_vftable *vfptr;
    IBaseClassBody base1; //sizeof(0x18)
    CClass::_vftable_for_IClass *vtable_18;
    IClassBody base2;
}
```

But, whenever I apply it to such functions, I get weird offsets.

I searched on the Internet for similar cases, and had no luck, so I'm hoping I can find an answer here.

Comment: "*This function returns `(this - 0x8)`*" - more accurately, it returns something more like `*(reinterpret_cast<int*>((reinterpret_cast<char*>(this) - 0x8))` instead. IOW, it is taking the value of the `this` pointer, subtracting 8 bytes from that value, and then returning the `int` value that is located at the calculated address.

Comment: Maybe it is casting from IBaseClass to CClass. This would require there were 8 bytes in CClass before the start of IBaseClass. Or maybe you simply chose the wrong class for this function.

Comment: Agreed. When dealing with inheritance, the compiler has to adjust the `this` pointer when accessing members of base/derived classes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling an assignment operator for one of bases with vtables of multiple-inherited derived class in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33593291/calling-an-assignment-operator-for-one-of-bases-with-vtables-of-multiple-inherit)

Comment: i'm grateful for your quick answers, and they inspired me a lot, so if i understood well that is a shifted pointer or so to speak, so for ex member at address -0x4 should be the very last member of the abstract class and for ex -0x18 is the very first member of the abstract class, that's seems right untill now by applying it to ida, but unfortunately there's no direct way to handle that pointer! or there's? please let me know if there's, and here's the reference that inspired me of the details i've just explained https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1695.shtml